# How do I get all the query string params from a request?

Tags: python, wsgi, gevent

I have setup a simple gevent wsgi server that will not be exposed to the outside world. I am trying to get all the querystring params but can only get the first:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from cgi import parse_qs
...
...
d = parse_qs(env.get('QUERY_STRING',''))
print d
```

curl localhost:5000?goat=pig&piano=guitar prints:

```
{'goat': ['pig']}
```

How can I get all params:

```
{'goat': ['pig'], 'piano': ['guitar']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use a web framework like Bottle or Flask for this type of utility.  The reason is that they are designed for this purpose, and handle things like request headers and JSON for you.

```
from bottle import route, request, response, template
@route('/forum')
def display_forum():
    forum_id = request.query.id
    page = request.query.page or '1'
    return template('Forum ID: {{id}} (page {{page}})', id=forum_id, page=page)
```

https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html

Comment: I did have flask but kept getting a "broken pipe" error. The solution was to use gevent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962925/flask-app-get-ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe. Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Like I said this will not be exposed to the outside world and will not have concurrent requests - just one at a time but Flask kept giving me that broken pipe error every other request.

Comment: I would use bottle, and gevent.  Bottle has an adapter to launch gevent correctly, so just use that.  Bottle also makes it easy to use the url route as variables.  I would take an hour and read the documentation.  It is the perfect tool for what you are doing.